# Free (open) linux antivirus

Tags: linux, anti-virus

Does anybody know any good **free** or **open source** [Clam](http://www.clamav.net/) alternative?

**Updete:**

There is good list at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_antivirus_software of course.

Comment: Why not ClamAV itself, if I might ask?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listed in no particular order. These are the antivirus applications I know that run on Linux.

1. Sophos
2. Trend Micro Server Project
3. RAV Antivirus
4. Vexira Antivirus
5. Panda Antivirus
6. AVG Antivirus
7. Avira Antivir

Also check [Open Antivirus](http://sourceforge.net/projects/openantivirus/).

Comment: With the exception of Open Antivirus, they are not free software / open source, though.

Answer (score 2):

You have the solution from Avira (Antivir), a free edition is available for Linux :
http://www.free-av.com/en/download/download_servers.php

Answer (score 0):

I use [fprot](http://www.f-prot.com/products/home_use/linux/) on linux:

> F-PROT Antivirus for Linux Workstations is FREE for use by personal users on personal workstations